# Android: JSONObject not valid value and API of Wordpress

Tags: android, json, wordpress, api

I have a list of posts from API-Wordpress. E.g: http://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts.
The struct of this json file is:

```
[{"id":"1","another_key":"another_value"}, 
{"id":"2","another_key":"another_value"}, 
{"id":"n","another_key":"another_value"}.
```

I have developed with this json file an application for IOS and this json file worked the fine.

When on Android app I call:

```
try{
            URL jsonURL = new URL(url);

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) jsonURL.openConnection();
            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            line = sb.toString();

            connection.disconnect();
            is.close();
            sb.delete(0, sb.length());  
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(line);
 ...
 ...
 }catch(...){...}
```

I achive this stacktrace:

```
  07-05 18:01:19.890 30260-30260/xxx.xxx D/JSONException: Value 
  [{"id":2361,"date":"2018-07-03T20:18:22","date_gmt":"2018-07- 
  03T18:18:22","guid":{"rendered":"https:\/\/www.xxx.com\/?p=2361"}...
  07-05 18:01:19.901 30260-30260/xxx.xxxW/System.err:     at 
  org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
```

What can I do for resolve it?
Thank's all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a JSONArray, not a JSONObject.

So try

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(line);
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem. I was sure I had tried this solution before posting the question.